# How can I save only one layer as a PNG file in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, export, png

I wanted save some layers as PNG files and I had opened a new window for every `.png` file and pasted in there and sometimes crop it.

Is there a way to export just a few or one selected layer and not the whole file much more easily, or maybe only save the visible part as a PNG?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose `File > Scripts > Export Layers To Files`

Select the `Visible Layers Only` option if you want to export only those layers that have visibility enabled in the Layers panel.

[image: Photoshop Screenshot of Scripts Menu]

[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7783a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7760a)

Answer (score 4):

**If you use Photoshop CC you don't need any script.**

You can activate the built-in function **"Generator"** (*File > Generator*). This function allow you to export layers and groups when you save the document. Simply rename your layers/group with the extension you need (like nav.png) and eventually the parameters.

With this method photoshop will export for you the named layers/group visible with associate layer style in the same directory of your file.

**See adobe article:**
http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2013/09/introducing-adobe-generator-for-photoshop-cc.html

Comment: This is truely awesome! You will be saving hundreds of hours of tedious copy/paste/safe!

Answer (score 2):

Skaught's solution works. There are two other options that come to mind.

1. Convert your objects (layers or groups) to **smart objects** then double click the SO in the layers panel to open a separate, exportable doc.
2. Use **slices** to delineate and set export prefs for your various objects. You can export by selected slices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found. Single-click layer exporting!
http://viget.com/inspire/single-click-layer-exporting-in-photoshop#the-best-way

Direct link to Photoshop action:
https://viget.com/uploads/file/generic/Inspire.atn.zip

Comment: Really Works! I've downloaded Action and pressed `F12`. And`Shift + F12` for Layer to new file.

Comment: @SergeySenkov, yeah, this is my #1 plugin/action for PS :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to select specific layers (or group of layers) then

1. Use Marquee Tool 'M' to draw the bounding box.
2. Use `Edit >> Copy Merged` to copy the specific content to new file (`png`, `psd`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In CC 2014, you can use the new feature **File>Extract assets** that will offer a dialog with all the visible layers and plethora of options (resolutions, prefixes, etc)  for extraction. Meant for web-developers this feature helped me out a lot. Too bad it's not available in other versions of PS.

From what I understand the feature is still under development and the pesky ".png" in the layer names will be removed, but for the time being watch out for the layer names.

Comment: i love adobe extract in brackets ...Best thing that ever happen to CSS and web design.