# Crop images from Layers in PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs3

I have a PSD file which contains many Layers and each layer contains either some image or text. I want to get/extract in a combined form e.g. one text layer and one image layer combined. Can any one help me how can I crop images from layers?

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction? [**how to save only one layer as png in adobe photoshop**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13424/8708)

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one help me how can I crop images from layers?

Well... I don't exactly fully understand what the end goal is so let me take a guess. One way that you could crop images from layers is to only hide all of the layers except the one that you want to make the crop size to be. Then go to `Menu`->`Trim`->`Transparent Pixels` && `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`->`OK` That will then trim the canvas size to just your visible layer now show again all the layers. Undo/Redo as necessary for other layers.

**Note**: For safety, save file as a copy before doing this so if you accidentally save and close you will still be able to get the full size file back.